# Laravel Get Input Value from array

Tags: arrays, checkbox, laravel

What's the right syntax of the codes below to get the checkbox value in an array

Here is the checkbox array:

```
@foreach($p->products as $pp)                        
     <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="{{ $pp->name }}"> {{ $pp->name }}<br />                            
@endforeach
```

And here's how I get the value

```
Input::get('product', 0) // this part how can i get the value from checkbox array if the user select more than one?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
$products = Input::get('product'); // Returns an array of values from the form

foreach ($products as $product)
{
   echo $product;
}
```

or

```
return $product; // Get them as an json
```